# Bottom border of JFrame don't appear

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border, layout-manager

I made a JFrame window but its bottom border don't appear. Only upper, left and right border appear. Border of JFrame means the visible line who margin the JFrame  window. It is unaesthetic.

```java
public GroupLayout metoda(Container host, Text_Dimensiune ...arg){
        
        ArrayList<JLabel> lista_etichete=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<JTextField> lista_text_field=new ArrayList<>();

        for(Text_Dimensiune i: arg){
            lista_etichete.add(new JLabel(i.getText()));
            lista_text_field.add(new JTextField(i.getDimensiune()));
                       
        }
        
        GroupLayout gl= new GroupLayout(host);
        host.setLayout(gl);
        
        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);       
        
        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup sg=gl.createSequentialGroup();
        
        for(int k=0; k<lista_etichete.size()-1;k++){
            sg.addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)  //de schimbat
                    .addComponent(lista_etichete.get(k))
                    .addComponent(lista_text_field.get(k),
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                            GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    );
            sg.addPreferredGap(RELATED, 
                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        Short.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        sg.addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)  //de schimbat
                    .addComponent(lista_etichete.get(lista_etichete.size()-1))
                    .addComponent(lista_text_field.get(lista_etichete.size()-1),
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                            GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    );
       
        gl.setHorizontalGroup(sg);
        
        
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup pg_etichete=gl.createParallelGroup(BASELINE);
        GroupLayout.ParallelGroup pg_text_field=gl.createParallelGroup();
        
        for(int k=0; k<lista_etichete.size();k++){
            pg_etichete.addComponent(lista_etichete.get(k));
            pg_text_field.addComponent(lista_text_field.get(k),
                    GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                    GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                    GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE             
            );
        }

        GroupLayout.SequentialGroup sgv=gl.createSequentialGroup(); //secvential grup pe verticala
        
        sgv.addPreferredGap(RELATED, 
                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        Short.MAX_VALUE);
        sgv.addGroup(pg_etichete);
        sgv.addGroup(pg_text_field);
        sgv.addPreferredGap(RELATED, 
                        GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 
                        Short.MAX_VALUE);
        
        gl.setVerticalGroup(sgv);
        
    return gl;    
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the post so that we see a minimal reproducable example with code that is running (and yes, showing the window with missing border), thanks.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.